# combine spring data JpaSpecificationExecutor with pagination and @Query

Tags: java, spring-data

```
we are working on spring boot project with spring data jpa and oracle and hibernate.
we have a lot of complex query,then we use @Query.so,for filtering we extend jpa repository from JpaSpecificationExecutor.but it only works with findAll() not findAllByxAndByz() or not work with @Query.(it's ok,each x and z are predicates) but not usfull for us.please help me if it has a right way!
```

consider in step1 we run a query like this:

```
@Query(value = "select p " +
            "from OCMPosts p join p.ocmUnitsByUntsUnitsId u where u.unitsId=:unitId",
            countQuery = "select count(p.postsId) from OCMPosts p join p.ocmUnitsByUntsUnitsId u where u.unitsId=:unitId")
    Page<OCMPosts> getPostsOfUnitByUnitId(@Param("unitId") Long unitId, Pageable pageable)
```

then in step2 we want to filter on step 1 result.for example if user input r return word contain r

Comment: we normally use @Query(value="{'xyz': ?0, 'abc': ?1}") with method returning ABC class or list of ABC i.e. List<ABC> and input paramter pass to the method as String x, String y, Sample code
@Query(value="{'xyz': ?0, 'abc': ?1}")
ABC getABC(String x, String y);
Can you please add your sample code for better understanding

Comment: i added sample to question

Comment: can Redis help us?

Comment: I want to understand why you want to again filter data which you can do while doing the query first time if we take your example suppose we want to filter based in column x then your code will be modified as 
@Query(value = "select p " +
            "from OCMPosts p join p.ocmUnitsByUntsUnitsId u where u.unitsId=:unitId and p.x=:test",
            countQuery = "select count(p.postsId) from OCMPosts p join p.ocmUnitsByUntsUnitsId u where u.unitsId=:unitId")
    Page<OCMPosts> getPostsOfUnitByUnitId(@Param("unitId") Long unitId,(@Param("test") String test, Pageable pageable)

Comment: consider a form in a web page each field on this form should be filter!

Comment: In that case insted of using Query annotation use session.createQuery and generate a dynamic query based in parameters passed from front end. Parameters passed should be a key value pair, key is column alias name and value is the if the filter you want to apply. To make is secure convert keys (alias name ) received from server to table column in backend